# Preloading CSS still results in render blocking sources

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-pagespeed

Im trying to preload some CSS in the following way

Inside the Head Tag:

```
<link rel="preload" href="css/layout.css" as="style">
```

Script at the bottom of the Body Tag (Don't think it matters where its placed anyway...)

```
<script>
var rels = document.querySelectorAll( 'link[rel="preload"]' );
function loadCSS(){
    for( var i = 0; i < rels.length; i++ ){
        if( rels[i].as !== undefined && rels[i].as === 'style' ){
            rels[i].rel = 'stylesheet';
            continue;
        }
        //IE fix
        if( rels[i].as === undefined && /(css)/i.test(rels[i].href)) rels[i].rel = 'stylesheet';
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    loadCSS();
};
```

however, if i invoke the `onload` event in the following way:

```
<link rel="preload" href="css/layout.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

It's not Render-Blocking, however not supported in IE.

What am i missing?

Comment: want to clarify,why you need to use js for loading css? do you have to meet some conditions and load the css style base on the result of the condition?

Comment: just preloading the CSS won't apply it, it has to be a valid type first.

Comment: you want to set the rel=" " into preload first, then change it to rel="stylesheet" later when the page loads completely?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//On window load
window.onload = function () 
{
    //Get the link tag using the ID
    var $style = document.getElementById('mycss');
    
    
    //Now you can add, remove or change its attribute, 
    $style.rel='stylesheet';
    
    //$style.href='';
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
         <!-- Put a unique ID to your link tag -->
         <link rel="preload" href="css/layout.css" as="style" id="mycss" />
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```